# Database Poller Java EE/Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using Java EE with the Spring Framework and Hibernate. I want to write a very simple database poller that does the following

1. Poll the DB every second
2. If a certain column in a certain row has the value that I want, stop polling and return success.
3. If polling has gone on for 10 or more seconds, return failure

I have already looked into Java's [ScheduledExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html) and [ExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html), and I think that I *may* be able to do what I want with these. My question is, **is there something built into Spring/Hibernate that can do this more elegantly?**

Comment: http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/04/postgresql-nofify-websocket-spring-mvc.html Shows how to notify client of db change, as an alternative to polling

Comment: What server are you using, my gut feeling is telling me that you are running a Spring on a Tomcat/Jetty -> i.e. not Java EE

Comment: We use Jetty. The codebase is written in Java EE

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the TaskScheduler like this:

1) create a bean with TaskScheduler

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(50);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Scheduler-Pool-");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

2) create a job scheduled with CRON notation

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.schedule(() -> aRunnable, new CronTrigger("0 0/5 * * * ?")); // per five seconds
```

3) when a condition is met or db poll timed out, disable the task

```
scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
```